# How to create a Google Sheets Script that runs as soon as the user opens a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

How do I create a script that runs as soon as the user opens a spreadsheet?

Specifically I need a script that when the spreadsheet is opened asks the name and sex of the user, and depending on the gender it adds the name to a different sheet of the spreadsheet.

This is simple but I've gone through the tutorials on their webpage and couldn't do it. I know how to program but I am new to Google Apps Scripts.

Also is this something done better in Google Forms or in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I create a script that runs as soon as the user opens a spreadsheet?

An [onOpen() trigger function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

> Specifically I need a script that when the spreadsheet is opened asks the name and sex of the user, and depending on the gender it adds the name to a different sheet of the spreadsheet.

The onOpen() should call a function that uses [Browser.inputBox()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox%28String%29) to get the user's input, then writes it to the sheet via [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues%28Object%29).

Note that the user will need to have edit privileges for this to work.

> Also is this something done better in google forms or in google spreadsheets?

If you want the UI to show up in a spreadsheet, then the script must be contained in a spreadsheet.

Alternatively, if you don't want the user to see the spreadsheet, you could use the Forms service to collect their input, with no need for any programming.

Comment: You were 9 seconds ahead ! :-) and better ;-(  (too busy right now :-|

Comment: @Mogsdad thank you for your answers but I think my question is even more basic: Where do I actually write the script? Do I create a spreadsheet and then write it somewhere? or do I go to script.google.com write the script there and somehow link it with my spreadsheet? Thank you. I guess these are really simple questions

Answer (score 1):

Nothing too hard to get that :

read [this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs?hl=fr-FR) on how to build an alert in a spreadsheet and make it show up using an installable trigger [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR)

all you have to do is put these together.

Answer (score 0):

For script lauched at opening you need write function:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ...
};
```

Google Spreadsheet don't have a dialog window or something similar.
But there are several ways:

1. You can use show method to show your html or UiApp input dialogbox: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#show(Object)
2. you can use one sheet for input "sex" and hide others sheets. After click button you can show all sheets. Here is SpreadSheet API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/
3. you can use information from profile logged person and read his/her sex :)
4. you can use Form for input "sex" and switch context (by script) to spreadsheet but this is more complex solution. Here is Form API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Yea, I forget about inputBox() :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a script that runs as soon as the user open the spreadsheet, you should create a bounded to a spreadsheet script and use a trigger:

1. Create a new or open an existing spreadsheet.
2. Click on Tools > Script editor...
3. Click the close button on the welcome dialog.
4. Start writing your script

To make the script run on open, you could use a simple trigger by using onOpen as the function name or you could use an installable trigger.

For further details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets