# Why doesn't my script run on opening the corressponding spreadsheet (I use onOpen(e) )?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following Google Apps Script code:

```js
function onOpen() {
  set_percentage(99);
}


function set_percentage(value) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ssid = "1C0sMrS8QuqWVCsgEkCbi2zzD-a5QrSuvlnvpVlgspHM";
  var ss = app.openById(ssid);
  var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
  s.getRange("B2").setValue(value);
}
```

When I open the target spreadsheet, the value `99` is not in `B2` cell, which indicates that the script does not run when the spreadsheet is opened.

I am using a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) because I don't want to create any custom menus, nor change anything in the GUI. The script runs fine when I manually execute it in the script editor, but not when the trigger fires.

### Similar question

I don't think this question is a duplicate. Authentication and permissions are crucial in the answer to my question - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004352/how-to-create-a-google-sheets-script-that-runs-as-soon-as-the-user-opens-a-sprea) is similar, but these things are not mentioned in the answers.

Comment: About `Why doesn´t my script run on opening the corressponding spreadsheet (I use onOpen(e) )?`, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. If you are using `onOpen` as the simple trigger, I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) In this case, please use the installable OnOpen trigger. At that time, please rename the function name from `onOpen` to another like `installedOnOpen` to avoid duplicate execution of `onOpen`.

Comment: [jinx @Tanaike]

Comment: @doubleunary I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `[jinx @Tanaike]`. So, I cannot know how I should respond to it. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: @Tanaike _**jinx:** Used after the same thing is said by two people simultaneously._ [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jinx#Interjection)

Comment: @doubleunary Thank you for replying. I understood it. Today, I can obtain new knowledge. I can use it in the future! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onOpen(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs in a context where it cannot access any personal information nor call services that would require authentication. The `openById()` method requires authentication, so it will throw an error when called from `onOpen(e)`.

When you execute the function through the **Run** button in the script editor, it runs under your account, and `openById()` works fine.

To make the code work, rename `onOpen(e)` to something like `installableOnOpen(e)` and run it through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Installable triggers run under the account of the user who set up the trigger.

You can check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for failed executions, and view those logs to find why code fails.